# passing values from one class to another android

Tags: java, android

Im trying to pass value from one class to another. I cannot use intent because the class extends a custom library and i cannot use bundles and stuffs(If im right). Here is what i have tried.

I have 2 classes callhelper.java which monitors Incoming and Outgoing calls.when an action is triggered, it populates data from DB and sends it to another class where it displays a popup.

callhelper class

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
             String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                String out = null;

            String query = "select * from ReminderTable" ;
            Cursor c2=   enter.selectQuery(query);
             //GetData and place it in out

    //Instance of 2nd class PopUpDisplay set = new PopUpDisplay();
    //passing out to function   set.setData(out);
    // calling 2nd class to display popup //  StandOutWindow.show(context, PopUpDisplay.class, StandOutWindow.DISREGARD_ID);
                     Toast.makeText(ctx, out, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             enter.close();
```

In popupdisplay class, i have a global variable and a method `setData()` which sets the value to the variable.

```
@Override
public void createAndAttachView(int id, FrameLayout frame) {
        // create a new layout from body.xml
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple, frame, true);
     tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvdisplaypoptitle);
        tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvdisplaypopnote);

        tv.setText(note);
        tv1.setText("Title");
    btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

}

public void setData(String a){
        note = a;
}
```

createAndAttachView is the method is where i want to set the textview to display my message which is passed from previous class. This method sets the layout for the Popup .The pop up is called in CallHelper class by `StandOutWindow.show()` method.

So, the problem is, whenever it displays the popup, it displays `null`. How can i make it display my message instead of null. what extra code should be put in? Please help regarding this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how abt using global constant variables? or shared pref? did u tried that?

Comment: i did not try shared prefs, Im new to android, can u please guide me? @diva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is run time data, it is not suggested to use sharedpreference. Create a class with name RunTimeData.java. Declare all required variables here as static. Whenever you need to save data, save it to these variables. After using the data in other class make sure you will relase the variables by setting them to null.

Example.

```
public class RunTimeData{
public static String name=null;
```

}

While assigning data do use as follows.

RuntimeData.name="yyyyy";

While using the data use as follows.

TextView tv=new TextView();
tv.setText(RunTimeData.name);

RunTimeData.name=null;

Release the variable when you are sure that you are not going to using the value once again somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Create a SharedPrefencesHelper class,make it have all the global variables you want to use in your various classes,then you can use these variables anywhere in your application with simple getter methods.Look up SharedPreferences,it's very easy to use.