# Android Studio - How to save value from button press and use value across app

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have code with three buttons. I want to assign, I believe, onClickListener to each of them. So that when each respective button is clicked, I get a value I can save and use in other activities.

Eventually I will use this value, to compare to another value selected via another activity, and depending on the matches (the two values), each will be assigned a random number between 1-6 and others.

Here is my .XML below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.android.cc09june.TeamAOffense">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Team A Offense Selection"
    android:id="@+id/TeamAOffSel"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/PandR"
    android:id="@+id/PandRA"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TeamAOffSel"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="exchange" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/MandF"
    android:id="@+id/MandFA"
    android:layout_below="@+id/PandRA"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="exchange" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/SandC"
    android:id="@+id/SandCA"
    android:layout_below="@+id/MandFA"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="exchange" />
```

Here is my .java below:

```
package com.example.android.cc09june;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
```

public class TeamAOffense extends ActionBarActivity {

```
public void exchange (View view){
    //need to make it link to TeamA.xml
    Intent intent = new Intent(TeamAOffense.this, ExchangeAToB.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_team_aoffense);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_team_aoffense, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
} }
```

Comment: You can use `SharedPreferences` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Comment: you can do this as well http://stackoverflow.com/a/27738934/1814225

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreferences, on your First Activity declare this on top

```
 SharedPreferences sharedpreference;
```

Then this on onCreate()

```
sharedpreference=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this.getBaseContext());
```

then on the onClick()

```
public void onClick(View view){
         sharedpreference.edit().putString("button_value",btn1.getText().toString()).apply();
}
```

then on other activities declare SharedPreferences again then:

```
String value = sharedpreference.getString("button_value","");
```

Comment: Would you mind breaking your answer down a bit more for me?

if I have THREE buttons, I have to place the code

'public void onClick(){
         sharedpreference.edit().putString("button_value",btn1.getText().toString()).apply();'

Where exactly?

Comment: Edited. I hope you will understand now

Comment: It's when you declare onClickListener like...

  btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                
        });

Answer (score 0):

As Jibran Khan suggested you can use shared preferences.

Get access to shared preference

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
  "your.app.package", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

In your onCreate method initialise the button and set on click listener for each of the button as follows:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id. SandCA);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //To edit shared preferences use editor as follows 
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("key","value");
        editor.commit();            
    }
});
```

In your other activity if you want to read the preferences again get the shared preferences object and

```
preferences.getString("key", "");// second parameter is default value.
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.
If you do not want to store string value you can use the relevant method like putLong, putBoolean, etc . .

For more information you can look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) or [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html).

If you find my answer helpful you can up vote my answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can set static value and get it everywhere you want.

```
public class DataManager {

private int value;


private static final DataManager instance = new DataManager();

private DataManager() {

}

public value getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}

public static DataManager getInstance() {
    return instance;
   }
}


DataManager.getInstance().setValue(10);
DataManager.getInstance().getValue();
```